# microsoft azure - cannoct delete CosmosDB resource

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I cannot delete CosmosDB resource, button Delete is Inactive.
System require enter right account name , I entered right name of resource but have still info :
The entered value does not correspond with ID of deleted resource.

[image: see screen]

Comment: Are you initiating the Delete operation from the CosmosDB blade or from the list of resources in your account (clicking in the three "...")?

Comment: After this post the resources disappeared themselves. I don't know why but there problem was resolved themselves